Create two functions to encode and then decode a string using the Rail Fence Cipher
This cipher is used to encode a string by placing each character successively in a diagonal along a set of "rails". First start off moving diagonally and down. When you reach the bottom, reverse direction and move diagonally and up until you reach the top rail. Continue until you reach the end of the string. Each "rail" is then read left to right to derive the encoded string.
For example, the string "WEAREDISCOVEREDFLEEATONCE" could be represented in a three rail system as follows:
W       E       C       R       L       T       E
  E   R   D   S   O   E   E   F   E   A   O   C  
    A       I       V       D       E       N

The encoded string would be:
WECRLTEERDSOEEFEAOCAIVDEN

I need 1 function/method that takes 2 arguments, a string and the number of rails, and return the encoded string
I also need a 2nd function/method that takes 2 arguments, the encoded string and number of rails, and return the decoded string.
For both encoding and decoding, assume number of rails >= 2 and that passing an empty string will return an empty string.
Some tests will include punctuation, don't filter them out as they are a part of the string.
I tried this:
def fence(lst, numrails):
    fence = [[None] * len(lst) for n in range(numrails)]
    rails = range(numrails - 1) and range(numrails - 1, 0, -1)
    for n, x in enumerate(lst):
        fence[rails[n % len(rails)]][n] = x

    if 0: # debug
        for rail in fence:
            return ''.join('.' if c is None else str(c) for c in rail)

    return [c for rail in fence for c in rail if c is not None]

def encode_rail_fence_cipher(string, n):
    return ''.join(fence(string, n))
    
def decode_rail_fence_cipher(string, n):
    rng = range(len(string))
    pos = fence(rng, n)
    return ''.join(string[pos.index(n)] for n in rng)

and it works for if the input is 0 or not there, but when I tried this:
WEAREDISCOVEREDFLEEATONCE

it returned this:
ERDSOEEFEAOCWAEICVRDLETNE

but it should be this:
WECRLTEERDSOEEFEAOCAIVDEN

The first function starts thus:
def encode_rail_fence_cipher(string, n):

The second function runs thus:
def decode_rail_fence_cipher(string, n):


What's your question? It seems like you need to learn how to use a debugger to debug your function.

Thats true, but I also need to find out why it isn't working.

Because your algorithm is wrong, obviously. If you step through it in a debugger, you should be able to see when you get values different from what you expect.

If you're learning to program, this is one of the most important skills.

I am still learning how to code, that's true, and I can't find anyone who can explain the basics to me in a way that I can understand.

also, can I have your help on one of my earlier questions?

rails = range(numrails - 1) and range(numrails - 1, 0, -1) almost certainly doesn't do what you expect. What are you trying to do with that?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
